# Add Permission to Lambda Function in Swagger Spec

Tags: aws-api-gateway

If I export my api gateway as Swagger and then use it in the body of a cloudformation template, I have to manually add permission to lambda function once the new api gateway is created from template.

[image]

Why doesn't export as Swagger handle this for me?  Is there anything I can add to the template to programmatically allow permission?

EDIT: So I finally got around to try the Serverless Application Model (SAM) as suggested below by Bob Kinney.  EXACT same problem.  Also when I go to do my manual fix (which is select edit lambda and then save without changing), this comes up:

[image]

Is SAM supposed to work this way?

Comment: Hit the same issue as you. If you solely just use SAM (let go Swagger integration) and define the lambdas with `RestApiId: Ref: yourAPIName`, it'll set up the permission of APIGateway->Lambda for you. Quite unfortunate that Swagger integration is lacking this permission creation (and nowhere mentioning this in the integration extension AWS doc). You'll have to create `"AWS::Lambda::Permission"` resource for each lambda or create a role, ... etc; don't think it's good developer experience.

Answer (score 1):

This dialog makes a call to the AWS Lambda service. Currently the Swagger import feature will not execute that call for you. You may want to look into the [serverless application model (SAM)](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model) as will encapsulate this permission, among other things.